# Can't remove a label programmatically

Tags: ios, label, cgrectmake

I am printing a label programmatically but I can't remove it from the screen. I have tried `removeFromSuperview` and `lbl1.hidden = YES;` and `lbl1= nil;` but non of them work. It stays on the screen all the time while I can see in the debug it pass from `ELSE` as in the code below.

Where would be my problem?

```
-(void)reloadData
lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 530, 550, 200)];

if (result1 > result2 &&  al == YES)
{
    lbl1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    lbl1.text = @" Warning!! ";
    lbl1.tag = 30;
    lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
    lbl1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl1.numberOfLines = 2;
    [self addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];
}

else{

    //Non of them is removing the label.
    [lbl1 removeFromSuperview];
    lbl1= nil;
    lbl1.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: in this case i think your method call multiple time please debug your code

Comment: Why do you init the label before the first `if` Since your don't add it to a view (addSubview), it's not on the screen. But, I think, that's because you ALWAYS do an alloc/init...
So, do the alloc/init if it doesn't exist only.

Comment: @Luai Kalkatawi - Whether my answer is worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you go into reloadData, you are creating a new label, so if you go into reload and jump to the else, you are creating a label, and then removing it.

You need to save that label as an instance variable and remove it/add it in your reloadData.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lbl1;
```

And in your code, do this only ONCE:

```
self.lbl1 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 530, 550, 200)] autorelease];
```

And in your reloadData do:

```
-(void)reloadData
lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 530, 550, 200)];

if (result1 > result2 &&  al == YES)
{
    self.lbl1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    //Etc...
}

else{

    [self.lbl1 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, I have did the same method you wrote but it didn't work. Should I test something else?

Comment: Hello Antonio this code works and it show and clean the label but when the label is empty and try to clean it I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
-(void)reloadData
if(!lbl1)
lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 530, 550, 200)];

if (result1 > result2 &&  al == YES)
{
    lbl1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    lbl1.text = @" Warning!! ";
    lbl1.tag = 30;
    lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
    lbl1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl1.numberOfLines = 2;
    [self addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];
}

else{

    //Non of them is removing the label.
    [lbl1 removeFromSuperview];
    lbl1= nil;
    lbl1.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: label removed...use this [self.view viewWithTag:30];

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove like this....

```
if (result1 > result2 &&  al == YES)
{
    lbl1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    lbl1.text = @" Warning!! ";
    lbl1.tag = 30;
    lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
    lbl1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lbl1.numberOfLines = 2;
    [self addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];
}

else{

    //Non of them is removing the label.
    [[self.view viewWithTag:30] removeFromSuperview];
    lbl1= nil;
    lbl1.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: (UILabel *) casting need not for label directly remove  [self.view viewWithTag:30];  it works fine...

Comment: I don't have a view in this file. How I can call view. @prabu

Comment: Try this [[self viewWithTag:30]removeFromSuperview]; @Luai

Comment: @prabu it didn't work. I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if the view is empty. How can I apply a method while it is empty don't check?

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi... you add label like [self addSubview:lbl1]; if the view is empty how to add label?